# Bash: Two for loops at once?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, for-loop

I am not sure how to do this at all.

I have two text files, `FILE1` and `FILE2`.

I would like to run a for loop for each file at the same time and display the 
contents next to each other.

For example,

`for $i in $(cat FILE1); do echo $i; done`

`for $j in $(cat FILE2); do echo $j; done`

I would like to combine these two commands, so I can run both files at the same time and have an output like `$i $j`

Comment: That is precisely what [`paste`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html) does.

Comment: If you don't want `paste` (though I guess you do) maybe look at [Looping over pairs of values in Bash](/questions/28725333/looping-over-pairs-of-values-in-bash)

Answer (score 3):

## Solution 1

Use the `paste` command

`paste FILE1 FILE2`

[Details for paste command](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/paste-command-linux-examples/)

[Another resource](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/paste.1.html)

## Solution 2

You can do this if they have the same number of lines.

```
#!/bin/bash
t=$(cat FILE1 | wc -l)
for i in `seq 1 $t`;
do
    cat FILE1|head -n $i|tail -n 1
    cat FILE2|head -n $i|tail -n 1
done
```

You can extend it to what you want for unequal number of lines.

Comment: Solution 2 is horribly inefficient, and should never be used.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using `for` loops at all; see [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Instead, use two `read` commands in a single `while` loop.

```
while IFS= read -r line1 && IFS= read -r line2 <&3; do
  printf '%s | %s\n' "$line1" "$line2"
done < FILE1 3< FILE2
```

Each `read` command reads from a separate file descriptor. In this version, the loop will exit when the shorter of the two files is exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different questions being asked here.  Other answers address the question of how to display the contents of the file in 2 columns.  Running two loops simultaneously (which is the wrong way to address the first problem) can be done by running them each asynchronously:  `for i in ${seqi?}; do ${cmdi?}; done & for j in ${seqj?}; do ${cmdj?}; done & wait`

Although you could also implement `paste -d ' ' file1 file2` with something like:

```
while read line_from_file1; p=$?; read line_from_file2 <&3 || test "$p" = 0; do
    echo "$line_from_file1" "$line_from_file2"
done < file1 3< file2
```

Comment: I just noticed that @chepner gave nearly this same solution, but I'll not delete mine since it addresses the issue of the files having different line lenghts.  But this is totally a hack and should never be done.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, in `bash` v4+ is to read the two files into 2 arrays, then echo the array elements side-by-side:

```
# Load each file into its own array
readarray -t f1 < file1
readarray -t f2 < file2

# Print elements of both arrays side-by-side
for ((i=0;i<${#f1[@]};i++)) ; do echo ${f1[i]} ${f2[i]}; done
```

Or change the `echo` to `printf` if you want the columns to line up:

```
printf "%-20s %-20s\n" ${f1[i]} ${f2[i]}
```

I'm not suggesting you do this if your files are 100s of megabytes.